# How to use Email attribute attachmentcount ?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I was thrilled when I saw the attribute attachmentcount on Email entity in MS Dynamics CRM 2015(I believe it's the same with MS Dynamics CRM 2013), but I can't seem to use it... not in the form and not as a column in a view.

Why can't I use this attribute??

Best Regards

Knut "Frustrated" Myre :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess its because its a special system field. Some system fields have particular behaviours and apparently this one means it cant be used on forms or views.

You could perhaps look into copying the value into another field using a workflow or plugin.